# GridLayoutAnimationControl Use

Tags: android, gridview

how can i use GridLayoutAnimationController in my gridview child. i want to apply two different animations to two gridview columns on the click of gridview.One gridview column can animate from top to bottom and one column animate from botton to top.

How can i achieve this?

Please help me.

I am using GridLayoutAnimationController but it can give the attribute errors.

I put my code below.

```
public GridLayoutAnimationController(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);

    TypedArray a = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs,
            com.android.internal.R.styleable.GridLayoutAnimation);

    Animation.Description d = Animation.Description.parseValue(
            a.peekValue(com.android.internal.R.styleable.GridLayoutAnimation_columnDelay));
    mColumnDelay = d.value;
    d = Animation.Description.parseValue(
            a.peekValue(com.android.internal.R.styleable.GridLayoutAnimation_rowDelay));
    mRowDelay = d.value;
    //noinspection PointlessBitwiseExpression
    mDirection = a.getInt(com.android.internal.R.styleable.GridLayoutAnimation_direction,
            DIRECTION_LEFT_TO_RIGHT | DIRECTION_TOP_TO_BOTTOM);
    mDirectionPriority = a.getInt(com.android.internal.R.styleable.GridLayoutAnimation_directionPriority,
            PRIORITY_NONE);

    a.recycle();
}
```